# How would I rewrite this VB script in Powershell?

Tags: vb.net, powershell

I have been trying different Powershell translations of a "find and edit strikethrough" function originally written in VB and can't find one that works. More broadly, I am converting a lot of old VB scripts to Powershell and there is certain syntax and commands that don't carry over neatly. Beyond this particular script, anybody have any resources that might help me do this more effectively than just guess and check?

Here is the VB function to replace strikethrough text:

```
Dim d As Object = GetDocument(handle,document_name)
Dim r As Object = d.Range

With r.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Font.StrikeThrough = True
    .Text = vfindtext
    .Replacement.Text = vreplacetext
    .Execute (Replace:=vReplaceType)
End With
```

And here is the last thing I tried in Powershell:

```
$word = new-object -comobject Word.application
$word.visible = $true
$doc1 = $word.documents.open($filename)
$range1 = $doc1.Range
$Format = $true


$range1.Find.ClearFormatting
$range1.Find.Font.Strikethrough
$range1.Find.Text
$range1.Find.Replacement.Text
$range1.Find.Text.Excecute.Replace(2)
```

I've tried several variations of this, different orders of method calls, different variable setups etc but can't find one that works.

I am trying to find strikethroughtext and either remove the strikethrough or delete the text. Right now I can't even get Powershell to identify the strikethrough though. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you feel that you need to use PowerShell for this? Seems similar to someone using a screwdriver as a hammer.

Comment: The company I'm working with is trying to create a library of powershell functions to replace VB code stages in Blue Prism. We may end up still using a mix of both but we're trying to see how much we can convert.

Answer (score 0):

This code is as noted not complete.

Try this refactor for the last code segment of your post, as a close-to-direct translation of the VBA:

```
$range1.Find.ClearFormatting 
$range1.Find.Font.StrikeThrough    = $true 
$range1.Find.Text                  = $vfindtext 
$range1.Find.Replacement.Text      = $vreplacetext 
$range1.Find.Execute($true, $false, $vReplaceType)
```

Comment: Thank you! Once this code hits the Fonts.Strikethrough line though it is jumping out of the program. If I comment out that line the next one does the same. I also tried putting whats on the right of the assignment operator in parentheses with the same result. Any idea what my issue might be?

Comment: Interesting... I'd have to test on my side, as what I provided was just off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

Ok figured it out. Using .range wasn't grabbing anything so all further methods ($range1.Find.etc...) were being called on a null variable. When I swapped $doc1.range for $doc1.content the assigned variable ($range1) became a com object and I was able to remove the strikethrough. This also fixed a remove highlight function I was trying. Below is the code that worked:

```
            $word = new-object -comobject Word.application
            $word.visible = $true
            $doc1 = $word.documents.open($filename)
            $range1 = $doc1.Content


            $range1.Find.Font.StrikeThrough
            $range1.Font.StrikeThrough = 0
              
            
            $test = $range1.Find.Highlight
            $range1.HighlightColorIndex = 0
```

Comment: Glad you worked this out, as I had a chance to mess with it as per your last comment shared.